# Singularity of a non- linear second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, stability-theory, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

I have the encountered a singularity in the equation below .
$$
y^{\prime \prime}(x)+\frac{2}{x} y^{\prime}+\left[y-\left(1+\frac{2}{x^2}\right)\right] y(x)=0, \quad 0<x<+\infty,
$$
with conditions
$$
y \in C[0,+\infty), \quad y(+\infty)=0
$$

I tried to  remove the singularity by referring to Bessel functions. I also tried to examine the asymptotic behaiour of the ODE by first eliminating the smallest terms i.e $ \dfrac{2}{x} y^{\prime} $ and $ \dfrac{2}{x^2}$ Before i code the solution numerically.  However , the equation seems to be more relatable with Emden - Fowler equations and the Lane- Emden equations as explained [here](https://scholarworks.uaeu.ac.ae/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1099&context=ejer). Is there any way i could be helped to over come this singularity ? Any suggestions are highly welcome.

Comment: At $x=0$ the asymptotic behavior is $y\approx cx$, the other monomial solution $c/x^2$ of $x^2y''+2xy'-2y=0$ diverges. The limit at infinity is $y''-y=0$ and has a saddle point at $y=0$, so the only asymptotic solution is $y=ce^{-x}$. Now you have to connect the two, for instance solving a boundary value problem with $ay'(a)-y(a)=0$ and $y'(b)+y(b)=0$ as boundary conditions.

Comment: @LutzLehmann. Thank you so much . So at x=0, is it correct to take , let's say $$
y=C_0+C_1 X+C_2 x^2+C_3 x^3 $$  or Taylors series ? if yes , then how does that work.

Comment: There is no constant term in the Frobenius series of the bounded solution. Otherwise yes.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, I tried to come up  with $$
y(x)=c x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n x^n
$$ but doesn't help me find the exact behaviour at x = 0 . Is there any suggestion you could give to me ?

Comment: It will only work for the linear terms. This makes for a quadratic defect in the equation, which integrates to a cubic or biquadratic error in the solution. So $c$ and $a_2$ should be calculable, perhaps also  $a_3$, after that it is less certain that the additional coefficients improve the solution. But in the interval $[a,b]$, $a$ can be chosen very small so that this initial error on $[0,a]$ is on the same magnitude as the average error of the regular numerical integration.